# Why does time constrained loop yield zero iterations on raspberry pi vs millions on PC?

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi

```
// set function to be called after 1 second
setTimeout(function() {
console.log('Timeout ran at ' + new Date().toTimeString());
}, 1000);

// store the start time
var start = new Date();
console.log('Enter loop at: '+start.toTimeString());

// run a loop for 4 seconds
var i = 0;
// increment i while (current time &lt; start time + 4000 ms)
while((new Date().getTime()) < (start.getTime() + 4000)) {
  i++;
}

//print out the loop count
console.log('Exit loop at: '
        +new Date().toTimeString()
        +'. Ran '+i+' iterations.');
```

I tried the above code on raspberryPi and the result was below

```
Enter loop at:Thu Feb 23 2017 13:30:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Exit loop at:13:30:57 GMT+0000 (UTC). Ran 0 iterations.
Time out atThu Feb 23 2017 13:30:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

While in a tutorial, the result is

```
Enter loop at: 20:04:50 GMT+0300 (EEST)
Exit loop at: 20:04:54 GMT+0300 (EEST). Ran 3622837 iterations.
Timeout ran at 20:04:54 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

Based on my result, it process with multi-thread, while in the tutorial's result, it's a single process. I really have no idea about which one is correct now.

Comment: Looks like &lt; is a side effect of some kind of copy paste? Replace it with <

Comment: javascript always run in a single thread, nop ?

Comment: It will not run with an `&lt;` as the code unless you're running it through some sort of thing that unbreaks it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Hmm, on rPi the timestamps are also identical.  [On raspberry pi there is no Real Time Clock (RTC)](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4373/20307) as on most PCs.  I wonder how the JavaScript engine deals with that.

Comment: Just copy and paste the original file from tutorial. I modified the &lt with < in my own code.

Comment: @Paul There's no RTC, that doesn't mean it doesn't keep track of time--it just mean it resets on power cycle/resets and gets its time from NTP, or loads from the last known time, or starts at the epoch (IIRC). Plus they're not identical--it exits a second later, and didn't increment `i`. It's probably something else. I don't have an rPi handy at the moment (took home the Pi0s yesterday) so I can't check anything :/

Comment: @eric How are you running the test on the rPi and the PC? E.g., what JS runtime etc.?

Comment: @DaveNewton That's a good suggestion, Currently, I run it on Pi3, I will run it on PC later

Comment: @DaveNewton I just confirmed that the some code on Pi3 and PC are different. I can get the same result as tutorial said on PC.

Comment: In node or in browser or...?

Comment: Oh, yep. I run it in Node. My node version is V7.1.0 on Pi and V4.4.7 on PC

Comment: That's strange, I get the some result on Mac and the node version on Mac is v4.4.3